# start sleep script need understanding

Tags: powershell

```
./backup.ps1
$job = Start-Job {$i=0; $c=0; while (1) { 
Write-Progress Activity "Step $i"; $i++; Start-Sleep -sec 1 }}
while ($job.State -eq 'Running' -And $c -lt 5) {
$c++;
$progress=$job.ChildJobs[0].progress; 
$progress | %{$_.StatusDescription}; 
$progress.Clear(); Start-Sleep 1 }
```

I have been trying to work around a script which waits for backup to complete and than executes the next block of code, but i could not do it with start-job and wait-job, i found the above code and pasted into my document and it worked, but as i am new to powershell i dont know what exactly this script is doing

Comment: *i am new to powershell i dont know what exactly this script is doing*  Just an aside you might want to [install the ISE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315244.aspx) You can step through the script and inspect the variables like any other modern IDE

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just pipe the job to out-null using this syntax?

`& ./backup.ps1|Out-Null`

This will wait to do next process until $job is done and released.

comment out everything after ./backup that is in regards to waiting for the script call to be finished.

You're just callling a PS script inside a PS script. if you want to wait for the first one to be done before you start your next task, add the `|Out-Null` to the end

Also - it's not going to have all the verbose output you have in your current set up. But it's quick, efficient, and much less code.

Comment: sorry i dint understand that is it possible if you can modify the above code and i reuse it to test if its working or not

Comment: where do you call your process to run? What code? You should be instantiating it somewhere...is it $job?

Comment: can any one please elaborate on this

Comment: i have modified in question my 1st line of code which is calling backup script is this ./backup.ps1